# google Oauth2.0 authenticate - not continue to redirect_uri

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-authentication, google-api-js-client

I'm trying to implement login with google to my web site.
The users can visit my site in 3 domains

1)  regular link (HTTP and WWW...)
2)  http://example.com - no www
3)  apps.facebook.com/example - facebook app

We want to allow the user connect google in those three options.

We're using gapi (google javascript library) in order to authenticate the user.
My code looks like:

```
   var config = {
        'client_id': 'my_client_id',
        'scope': 'my_scopes',
        **'redirect_uri' : "https://www.example.com/oauth/",**
        'immediate': immediate
    };
    **gapi.auth.authorize(config, function(){});**
```

As you can see I'm setting my redirect uri as part of the config of gapi. 
We've created some popup in order to give the same uri for the three domains.

My problem is that in case I'm login to my site from the domain without the WWW, the authorize isn't working and the user isn't redirect to the redirect_uri link - which means, we don't have his token.

In case I'm removing the WWW in the redirect_uri (so it will looks like https://example.com/oauth/)
the facebook domain isn't working...

It's so frustrated..
Is anyone familiar with this kind of problem?
Any idea?

We've spent on it too many hours....

Thanks
Z

Answer (score 1):

You can register multiple redirect URIs for a single client in the Google API Console so you would register one for each domain and pass the one for the currently accessed domain in the `redirect_uri` parameter of the authorization request. You don't need to use the same redirect URI across your domains so that should solve your state/token restoration problems. [image]

Comment: we've tried to work with couple of redirect_uris but then we had a problem that **the auth popup not always closed..** So we choose to pop our own popup, save the token there, send it to the server and then back to the client in order to use it for the next calls..

Comment: I think that would be a different question then, to try and debug why the popup does not always close. In any case I'd recommend not to use a popup but a full browser redirect as that is what is the recommended approach and best practice for external login anyway.

Comment: Really? as far as we see in other sites they working with the google authentication popup and after the login it closed it.. (check pinterest)

Comment: Popup makes it harder for the user to recognize the legitimacy of the IDP pages and harder for the IDP to provide a universally working and well-displaying login page; Google allows login through popup by explicit exception only because they use X-Frame-Options to do frame busting.

Comment: I think my direction should focus on the HTTPS and HTTP link... It might be the problem there

Comment: you can go from http to https (in request->response) but not the other way around

Comment: We solve the problem. The issue was related to our popup form and not to google.. Thanks a lot Hans for your help